# Why do people keep shooting at Jedi?

Tags: star-wars

In the movies and the various TV shows shooting blasters at Jedi is shown to be utterly ineffective. They bat the blasts away like flies with their lightsabers.

As was noted in [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51824/outside-of-order-66-does-a-blaster-ever-beat-a-lightsaber) shooting at Jedi very rarely works and far more often results in the blast being deflected back at the attackers.

This fact is well known to the various militaries. The Empire and the Separatists both had extensive experience of it. Yet their troops keep trying and trying to shoot Jedi.

What is the in-universe explanation for making no effort to develop better tactics?

Comment: The problem is that we spend most of our time with what basically boils down to Jedi royalty, the best of the best of the best (with honours) who're essentially near-immortal killing machines. The rest of the order isn't nearly so powerful.

Comment: Plus even powerful Jedi can be shot if there enough simultaneous shots that they can't block or dodge _all_ of them.

Comment: Next you'll be asking why no one who fights Jedi has ever invented artillery or hand grenades.

Comment: Why do people keep shooting at Superman? At least a Jedi can make mistakes.

Comment: I'm asking about the in-universe explanation for this tactic. The other question is only tangentially related, at most it only serves to prove the point.

Comment: The top two answers in the dupe address this. They keep doing it because it keeps working.

Comment: I'm at a loss why this has been reopened. Any answer to this would likely draw on examples straight from the [dupe question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51824/outside-of-order-66-does-a-blaster-ever-beat-a-lightsaber).

Comment: There's relatively few Jedi across the entire galaxy; the vast majority of people with blasters simply never would have encountered one before, and the few who do rarely survive long enough to figure out how ineffective the weapon is and tell others.

Comment: @Valorum because the "dupe" doesn't answer this. It gives a few odd examples of times it worked but that doesn't explain why soldiers are trained to use a tactic that only works about 1 in a million times, and don't notice that their comrades are being slaughtered and change tactics. The clones acknowledge it and incorporate it into their tactics, after all.

Comment: @user - It doesn't work "one in a million". When we see it being used on anything other than Jedi uber masters, it's pretty darned effected.

Answer (score 11):

I think the best answer, which can be drawn from the movies themselves, is that it is the best tactic. We see the Clones kill tons of Jedi in Episode III, inside their own temple. In the brief look we get at this attack, we can assume it was a surprise attack, and the Jedi may not have realized it was an assault until the shooting started, since Anakin was leading them. In the one shot we see of them actually killing Jedi in the temple, they appear to be surrounding them and shooting them from all angles. They're simply overwhelmed, and unable to properly block so much laser fire at once. Though it does lead to casualties, I think that's just to be expected in the eyes of the Empire or any other enemy force. Jedi are pretty much the most dangerous fighter you'd face in any battle situation, and in terms of military strategy, the losses would be seen as justified if they managed to take out a Jedi. In the case of the Clones, I don't think Palpatine particularly cared about them beyond their usefulness as tools for overthrowing the Jedi. He probably wouldn't bother assigning anyone to create better strategies for killing them when he has millions of soldiers at his disposal. In general, Palpatine doesn't care about anyone but himself, and everyone else is expendable if they serve no further use to him. Same with a crime lord like Jabba. He only cares about his own survival, and doesn't care about the loss of mercenaries that can be bought for fairly cheap. Outside of the prequels, there really aren't a lot of Jedi left to deal with in general, so the explanation there would be that there isn't much point in dedicating extra training for it if there are pretty much no Jedi left, and you can overwhelm them with large numbers regardless.

As far as other tactics go, throwing a grenade (thermal detonator) would probably lead to it being force pushed back at you, killing you and your fellow soldiers. There aren't a lot of other weapons shown in the movies themselves, but even in comics, video games, books, etc., where more liberty is taken with the available technology, Jedi are usually able to avoid being killed by other kinds of weapons by outmaneuvering, force pushing, or blocking/reflecting them with their lightsabers. Overwhelming force or luring them into a trap are really the only methods that have a major effect, unless you know a dark side user who can take them on in an even fight.

I understand your point about in canon explanations, but I don't think there really are any, at least not from what I've seen. But I think you can infer from what we see in the movies that most Jedi are simply too dangerous for most of the other potential methods to be effective. The best solution really is shooting at them. You're using a long ranged weapon, and there's at least a slight chance you may land a shot, especially if you have help. It's a better tactic than nothing I suppose, when facing an enemy that is extremely dangerous, but also fairly rare.

One last point I have is for the separatists. More advanced weapons did exist during the clone wars, but they likely weren't widespread because it would cost more money than continuing to mass produce the designs they already ahd. A lot of Jedi actually did die in the clone wars simply because they were overwhelmed by laser fire. The best example of this is in Episode II, where 200 Jedi went to Geonosis and fought in the arena. They are overwhelmed by the droids, and are shot down until there are about 15 to 20 of them left at most (it's never stated in the film itself that there are 200 Jedi, only in expanded material, but even without that number, there are still a lot of them onscreen). Jango Fett was even able to kill one at almost point blank range, which I admit is dumb, but his blaster fires pretty quickly, so it was enough to overwhelm the Jedi. The battle of Geonosis shows that it is an effective method, you just need a lot of guns, and preferably an enclosed space where you can surround them.

Comment: Great answer! Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 4):

As BLLG Ultraversal has pointed out, you can overwhelm a Jedi if several people are firing at him at the same time.

But even if you're alone, it helps you. You might not kill a Jedi with firing at it with a standard blaster. However, you slow him down as he has to concentrate on deflecting the shots not to be killed. Otherwise, they may simply run towards you and use the force to speed them up. If you shoot at them, they (at least partially) need the Force to deflect.

Furthermore, there is a small chance that you indeed hit the Jedi. That's still better than just standing there and waiting for your death.

As stated in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/13699/120088), there are tactics against Jedi:

> The real reason Slugs > Blasters against Jedi is really more straightforward than you'd think.
>
> - Blaster bolts can be reflected, slugs will be burned up by the blade. This removes a significant counterattack from the Jedi.
> - Slug-throwing weapons have a higher rate of fire. Jedi might seem impervious in the movies, but anyone can make a mistake. More projectiles = greater odds. Additionally, as others have pointed out, the higher rate of fire means more difficulty deflecting them.
> - Slugs probably travel much faster than blaster bolts. While there is some controversy about the exact speeds of blaster bolts, based on a visual summary of the films it is clear that they travel much slower than even the slowest bullets on earth do. Speed counts against Jedi.
> - Slugs are more difficult to see. While perhaps not always a total win against Jedi, less visibility is always an advantage.

Also, see [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/144006/120088) that projectile melt and pass through lightsabers. Therefore, firing at them is a valid self-defense option.

Humans have the *[fight or flight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fight-or-flight_response)* response to a stressful event (and I'd count a Jedi running towards you with an activated lightsaber as a stressful event). So, basically, you either run away or attack (fire your weapons) in hope to survive. They might be counscious that their behaviour is more or less useless but their instinct / survival mode goes into "fire everything" mode.

Comment: If in doubt: Shotgun.

Comment: *"Slugs are difficult to see"*


They are for us, observers, Jedi do not rely on hindsight, but on Force sensitivity, which allows them to predict where every slug is at the precise moment in time. Plus, it gives them superhuman speed to be able to position the blade precisely to that position. 

And, for someone like Darth Vader (or Kylo Ren), it gives them the ability to stop anything incoming with a wave of a hand, without any blade.

Otherwise, I think it is a good answer

Comment: @JoeBloggs Shotgun, Flamethrower or simply nuke it from orib

Comment: @TimSparrow I agree. But as I've been quoting an accepted answer, I did not want to change it.